# Why for each loop is not applicable for JSON array

Tags: android, json, foreach

When I was trying **to parse a json array**, the studio gave me a compilation error stating **foreach is not applicable for json array**.
Although I know how to get all objects and parse; I just wanted to know **why foreach is not applicable** even though the json array is an array

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Add some part of code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For each loop works like this -

For example for and Integer type `ArrayList<Integer> list;`

```
for (int x : list)
    // process x here
```

But a JSONArray can have any type of value inside it.

For example -

```
[{"name" : John}, {"name" : Joe}, 1, false]
```

This is a valid JSONArray but it contains all kinds of objects namely - JSONObject, Integer, Boolean. So we would get a different type of value each time in for each loop.

So to apply a for each loop on this array we'll have to cast everything to Object class first -

```
for (Object o : myJsonArray)
```

Which doesn't makes much sense and would require a lot of useless effort.

Answer (score 9):

Because `JSONArray`class doesn't implement `Iterable` interface.

Answer (score 4):

Because `JSONArray` derives from `Object` and foreach expects the collection to be iterable.