# Android: get child of Object

Tags: android, arrays, json, object

My code is :

```
Object value = tasks.get(key);
```

result `value` is : `[{"name":"one","family":"yes"},{"name":"two","family":"no"}]`

Now i want get child of `value` in foreach

```
foreach(...){
    String name = ...
    String family = ...
}
```

Comment: get that Object converted into a jSON array and iterate over it and get each object out of it and read the string values!    or simply go POJO making and GSON lib use!

Comment: foreach not applicable to type JSONArray. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771392/why-for-each-loop-is-not-applicable-for-json-array) You have to manually parse the response or have to use Gson library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your value is in JSONArray format.

Use this:

```
JSONArray values = new JSONArray((String) tasks.get(key)); // or alternative task.getString(key)
for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject entry = values.getJSONObject(i);
  String name = entry.getString("name");
  String family = entry.getString("family");
}
```

Comment: I get this error `org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class org.json.JSONArray`

Comment: print `tasks.get(key)` before you parse it. Make sure it starts from `[` and not `{`

Comment: I added a String cast. I don't know what your task ist. Maybe there is a `task.getString(key)` too.

Comment: I get error now : `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Answer (score 0):

Object itself not containig fields or something, you have to create `pojo` *(just if you want clean and resuseble code)* in order to get fields from it, for example, using `Gson`

**Add dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

**Add pojo:**

```
public class Pojo{
   @SerializedName("name")
   @Expose
   private String name;
   @SerializedName("family")
   @Expose
   private String family;
}
```

**Convert:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Pojo pojo = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), Pojo.class);
```

Comment: @B001ᛦin order to reuse it, and not copy paste code to reuse it, or in order to not write code to parse json, or in order to not add more code to parse json when new fields arrived.

Comment: @B001ᛦ I provided edit, you also could/

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Convert Object instance into String

```
String response = (String) value;
```

Step 2: Feed the String instance into JsonArray

```
//don't forget to caught JSONException here
JsonArray array = new JsonArray(response);
```

Step 3:
Iterate through JsonArray and get values from each JsonObject

```
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

           //get values here
           String name = object.getString("name");
           String family = object.getString("family");
        }
```

Now, the whole code should look like this

```
 try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray("");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
           String name = object.getString("name");
           String family = object.getString("family");
        }
    } catch (JSONExceptione) {
      //do something..
    }
```

**Important**
If you still don't know what happened, this whole process is called JSON parsing. Learn about it.